# Uninstall SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server

I want to uninstall SQL Server, and try to follow the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=Windows10#uninstall

But when I search for sql in Apps then there are no results. I cannot see the "Apps and Features" and I only see Default Apps. Even when I log-in with an elevated account I cannot see "Apps and Features".
What are my options for uninstalling SQL Server?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the installer?...you should always be able to run that manually and I believe do an uninstall that way.

Comment: @J.D. I don't think one can uninstall with installation center. Is that what you are meaning with "installer"?

Comment: cannot see the "Apps and Features"- do need someone with local admin privilege in the host? I can see "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (64-bit)" under "Apps & features"  on both windows 10 and 11

Comment: @SqlWorldWide: even when I log in my admin account the "Apps and Features" is not there...

Comment: I do not know why. This article by Aaron Bertrand might help. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/

Comment: @SqlWorldWide: thanks looks useful.